# Timezone changes in reverse direction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

So I'm currently changing 14:45 EST to GMT which would be 19:45 GMT, since there's a 5 hour difference. However what my code is doing, is that it's reversing the time so instead of showing 19:45 GMT, which is the correct time it's showing 09:45, which turns out to be -5 hours not +5 hours like I want.

Here's the code I'm currently using

```
       NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"]];
        [df_utc setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

        NSDateFormatter* df_local = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df_local setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        [df_local setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

        NSString *ts_utc_string = [df_utc stringFromDate:dateFromString];

        NSString *ts_local_string = [df_local stringFromDate:dateFromString];

        NSLog(@"UTC TIME: %@",ts_utc_string);
        NSLog(@"LOCAL TIME: %@",ts_local_string);
```

Basically UTC TIME prints 09:45 while LOCAL TIME: prints 14:45, however I want to UTC time to print 19:45.

```
[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] = GMT +0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the "EST" timezone to `df_utc`, and the system timezone (GMT) to
`df_local`. It should be the other way around.

Note that `[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]` is a better way to obtain the UTC/GMT
timezone, without relying on the system timezone.

Also you are converting the same date to a string twice, instead of "string (EST) -> date -> string (UTC)". The following code produces the result that you expect:

```
NSString *ts_local_string = @"14:45";

NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[df_utc setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSDateFormatter* df_local = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df_local setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"]];
[df_local setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSDate *date = [df_local dateFromString:ts_local_string];
NSString *ts_utc_string = [df_utc stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"UTC TIME: %@",ts_utc_string);
NSLog(@"LOCAL TIME: %@",ts_local_string);
```

Output:

```
UTC TIME: 19:45
LOCAL TIME: 14:45
```